# Reading from array even with DispatchGroup issue

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am having an issue where I am taking strings from firebase collection and displaying them in a collection view.

Basically I believe the firebase function is not executing quickly enough for the program so I put it in a DispatchGroup which also did not solve the problem

```
 //arrays of names and descriptions
    var names:[String] = []
    var descriptions: [String] = []
```

Here is the firebase function which works in retrieving the names and descriptions from firebase

```
func firebase()
{
    //connection to firebase for the names and descriptions
    let db = Firestore.firestore()

    db.collection(test).getDocuments { (snapshot, err) in

        if let err = err {

            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            for document in snapshot!.documents {
                let name = document.get("Name") as! String
                let description = document.get("Description") as! String
                //Add names and descriptions to the arrays
                self.names.append(name)
                self.descriptions.append(description)
            }
            for x in self.names{
                print(x)
            }
            for y in self.descriptions{
                print(y)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the ViewDidLoad function:
which works perfectly when I do not try to print the names[0]

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let myGroup = DispatchGroup()
    myGroup.enter()
    firebase()

    // When your task completes
    myGroup.leave()
    myGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
        // do your remaining work
        print(self.names[1])
        self.setupBottomControls()
        self.setupTopControls()
        self.setupButton()

        self.setupImages()

        self.collectionView?.backgroundColor = .white
        self.collectionView?.register(PageCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellId")

        self.collectionView?.isPagingEnabled = true
    }
}
```

I keep getting the error:

```
Fatal error: Index out of range
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misusing `DispatchGroup`. It's inappropriate in this case.

Just add a completion handler

```
func firebase(completion: @escaping () -> Void)
{
    //connection to firebase for the names and descriptions
    let db = Firestore.firestore()

    db.collection(test).getDocuments { (snapshot, err) in

        if let err = err {

            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            for document in snapshot!.documents {
                let name = document.get("Name") as! String
                let description = document.get("Description") as! String
                //Add names and descriptions to the arrays
                self.names.append(name)
                self.descriptions.append(description)
            }
            for x in self.names{
                print(x)
            }
            for y in self.descriptions{
                print(y)
            }
            completion()
        }
    }
}
```

And use it

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    firebase() { [unowned self] in
         DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // do your remaining work
            print(self.names[1])
            self.setupBottomControls()
            self.setupTopControls()
            self.setupButton()

            self.setupImages()

            self.collectionView?.backgroundColor = .white
            self.collectionView?.register(PageCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellId")

            self.collectionView?.isPagingEnabled = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: great answer @vadian

Answer (score 0):

Your DispatchGroup will not work like that, because it will just pass away and your name will be still empty if you try to access the data.

Try this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        firebase()
    }

    func firebase() {
        let myGroup = DispatchGroup()
        myGroup.enter()

        Firestore.firestore().collection(test).getDocuments { (snapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            } else {
                for document in snapshot!.documents {
                    let name = document.get("Name") as! String
                    let description = document.get("Description") as! String
                    //Add names and descriptions to the arrays
                    self.names.append(name)
                    self.descriptions.append(description)
                }
            }
            myGroup.leave()
        }

        myGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
            setupView()
        }
    }

    func setupView() {
        setupBottomControls()
        setupTopControls()
        setupButton()
        setupImages()

        collectionView?.backgroundColor = .white
        collectionView?.register(PageCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellId")

        collectionView?.isPagingEnabled = true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The only place I can see the potential for an out of bounds exception here is

```
print(self.names[1])
```

You can likely put a breakpoint there and manually inspect the names array (`po self.names`)

#### You have the wrong approach but I'm going to fix your code for reference THEN suggest what you should do

Anyways that should get you thinking of why that's happening, the problem is with these lines of code:

```
    myGroup.enter()
    firebase()

    // When your task completes
    myGroup.leave()
```

Your comment is wrong. The firebase func you posted has some async code - so it will finish and continue onto the `myGroup.leave()` func almost immediately. You want to leave when the async code is complete.. The most standard way to accomplish this is definitely to just use a completion handler instead of `DispatchGroup` (vadian posted that solution while I was writing). But just to illustrate your mistake:

```
func firebase(dispatchGroup: DispatchGroup) {
    ...
    // this is an async call vv
    db.collection(test).getDocuments { (snapshot, err) in
        ... // all the code
        // NOW that you're done, leave the group
        dispatchGroup.leave()
    }
}
```

then you can pass it in as:

```
    myGroup.enter()
    firebase(dispatchGroup: myGroup)
```

However... you shouldn't wait for that response to do basic layout code.. I'm not sure which of these methods actually use `self.names` or `self.descriptions` but any of these lines that don't can just be executed right away:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    firebase()

    self.setupBottomControls()
    self.setupTopControls()
    self.setupButton()

    // im going to pretend this function relies on the self.names/self.descriptions
    // self.setupImages()

    self.collectionView?.backgroundColor = .white
    self.collectionView?.register(PageCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellId")

    self.collectionView?.isPagingEnabled = true

}
```

then once the firebase function finishes well just call the one that relies on the data...

```
func firebase()
{
    //connection to firebase for the names and descriptions
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    db.collection(test).getDocuments { (snapshot, err) in
        // code
        // now that im done and I have the data...
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.setupImages()
            // self.collectionView.reloadData() // also maybe this??
        }
    }
}
```

you don't have to do everything in `viewDidLoad` just do it when it's ready.